# How to match columns which starts with particular string and ends with other particular string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have code:

```
import pandas as pd



data = {'spike_starts': [1,2,3], 'ends_spike_starts': [4,5,6], 'ends_spike': [7,8,9], 'not': [10,11,12], 'castle': [13,14,15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
colNames_starts = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = '^spike')].tolist() 
print("Starts")
print(colNames_starts)



print("\n")
print("----------------------------------------")
colNames_ends = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'spike$')].tolist() 
print("Ends")
print(colNames_ends)
```

`colNames_starts` - list contains column names which name starts with `spike`.

`colNames_ends` - list contains column names which name ends with `spike`.

**Question:** How to modify regex part of above code to get column names in list which are starting with `ca` and ending with `le`? So in my example list should contain `castle`.

Comment: Use `^ca.*le$`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. That worked.